# JS: How to detect if location is disabled on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've built a web app using jQuery Mobile. My question is: using JS (jQuery or Vanilla), how can my web app detect if geolocation is disabled on a mobile device?

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862019/check-if-location-setting-has-been-turned-off-in-users-browser ?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and it worked perfectly. Thank you!
P.S. Perhaps you should write this as an answer (maybe including a snippet of the code). If you do, I will mark it as the accepted answer. This way, it will be more visible to other people who are looking for this answer.

Comment: Most suitable option is mark your question as duplicate, or edit it and point to the other answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/).

You can initialise with the tests you need, of which Geolocation is one of them.

As per the docs you can try something like this:

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.geolocation,
    yep : 'geo.js',
    nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

Where in this example it tests for geolocation and then selectively loads a javascript file depending on the result.

It will also add a `.geolocation` class to the body DOM element if the device supports it, so you can simply test to see whether this class exists in order to determine if geolocation is supported / enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, this web app is for a university assignment, and we are not allowed to use any plug-ins. Thanks for you help!